# Why doesn't JavaBeans serialize a property from type List<?>?

Tags: java, javabeans

I'm trying to do some simple XML serialization with JavaBeans, with an object having five getter/setter properties, and two getters. These two are from type List<...> :

```
public List<MasterDataQueryMDType> getType() {
    if (type == null) {
        type = new ArrayList<MasterDataQueryMDType>();
    }
    return this.type;
}
```

and

```
public List<MasterDataQueryKey> getKey() {
    if (key == null) {
        key = new ArrayList<MasterDataQueryKey>();
    }
    return this.key;
}
```

I'm then using the XMLEncoder class (although here JAXB may be more appropriate, but I'm keeping it simple for now). The resulting XML has only the five getter/setter properties, the two properties of type List haven't been encoded. Is it because they are read only, or do I have to write a PersistenceDelegate for those kind of generic Lists ?

---

Okay I've researched more, and the easiest way to solve this without going mad with writing its own PersistenceDelegate seems to be the creation of a wrapper class :

```
public class MasterDataQueryWrapper {
private MasterDataQuery query;

public MasterDataQuery getQuery(){
    return this.query;
}
public void setQuery(MasterDataQuery value){
    this.query = value;
}
public List<MasterDataQueryMDType> getType(){
    return query.getType();
}
public void setType(List<MasterDataQueryMDType> value){
    for (MasterDataQueryMDType t:value){
        this.query.getType().add(t);
    }
}
public List<MasterDataQueryKey> getKey(){
    return query.getKey();
}
public void setKey(List<MasterDataQueryKey> value){
    for (MasterDataQueryKey k:value){
        this.query.getKey().add(k);
    }
}
}
```

That way, java Beans has no problems getting and setting the read-only properties. However if you have a more elegant solution, feel free to chime in...

Comment: However there are some minor errors thrown by the encoder : java.lang.NullPointerException
Continuing ...
java.lang.InstantiationException: java.math.BigDecimal
Continuing ...
java.lang.RuntimeException: failed to evaluate: <unbound>=Class.new();
Continuing ...
java.lang.InstantiationException: java.math.BigDecimal
Continuing ...
java.lang.RuntimeException: failed to evaluate: <unbound>=Class.new();
Continuing ...

Comment: Are you aware, that the interface List itself does not extend serializable? Could your problems origin there? Also: is `MasterDataQueryMDType` serializable?

Comment: Yes, 'MasterDataQueryMDType' is serializable, but it seems the problem here was that the properties 'getKey' and 'getText' in the original class were read-only, which is not javaBeans-conform. In this case, the XMLEncoder simply ignores those properties. With my solution, I provide a wrapper class which simply adds a setter for those two properties, and then everything is serialized.

Answer (score 0):

After testing and reflexion, it seems my solution is the easiest in the context of JavaBeans, simply create the wrapper class...