# How to bind ObjectProperty<LocalDate> to StringProperty in JavaFX?

Tags: java, javafx, data-binding, datepicker

I'm trying to bind between two different properties.
How can i bind `ObjectProperty<LocalDate>` to `StringProperty`?

Task Class

```
 public class Task {

    StringProperty time = new SimpleStringProperty();
    ObjectProperty<String> testCase = new SimpleObjectProperty<>();
    StringProperty date = new SimpleStringProperty();

    public Task(String date, String time, String testCase) {
        this.date.set(date);
        this.time.set(time);
        this.testCase.set(testCase);
    }

    public String getdate() {
        return date.get();
    }

    public void setDate(String date) {
        this.date.set(date);
    }

    public StringProperty dateProperty() {
        return date;
    }
    }
```

Controller Class

```
public class Controller implements Initializable {

@FXML
private DatePicker datePicker;

private Task currentTask = new Task();

@Override
public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
   datePicker.valueProperty().bindBidirectional(currentTask.dateProperty());
      }
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to make `date` in `Task` an `ObjectProperty<LocalDate>`?

Comment: I can't because need to convert my Task class to a XML File. XML encoder doesn't support LocalDate @James_D

Comment: I haven't worked much with XML encoders, but I'm pretty certain there is a way to do that...

Comment: You can certainly do this using JAXB: see https://stackoverflow.com/q/36156741

Comment: And it seems you can with `XMLEncoder` too: https://stackoverflow.com/q/41373566/

Comment: Indeed that was another option! Thanks a lot @James_D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like it would make more sense to make `Task.date` an `ObjectProperty<LocalDate>`, if it is supposed to represent a date. Then you can just bind them bidirectionally in the usual way:

```
public class Task {

    private ObjectProperty<LocalDate> date = new SimpleObjectProperty<>();

    // ...

    public ObjectProperty<LocalDate> dateProperty() {
        return date ;
    }

    public final LocalDate getDate() {
        return dateProperty().get();
    }

    public final void setDate(LocalDate date) {
        dateProperty().set(date);
    }
}
```

and then of course

```
datePicker.valueProperty().bindBidirectional(currentTask.dateProperty());
```

works exactly as needed.

Note that, since in the comments you say you are using a `StringProperty` as you are marshaling the data with an `XMLEncoder`, it is perfectly possible to use this approach in that context. See [LocalDate serialization error](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41373566/)

---

If you really want this to be a `StringProperty` (and I should emphasize, it really doesn't make sense to do it this way), you can use a `StringConverter`:

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE ;

StringConverter<LocalDate> converter = new StringConverter<LocalDate>() {
    @Override
    public LocalDate fromString(String string) {
        return string == null || string.isEmpty() ? null : LocalDate.parse(string, formattter);
    }
    @Override
    public String toString(LocalDate date) {
        return date == null ? null : formatter.format(date);
    }
};
```

And finally:

```
currentTask.dateProperty().bindBidirectional(datePicker.valueProperty(), converter);
```